# VLC shows all subtitles in italic and/or bold, depending on font

Tags: windows-8, vlc-media-player, subtitles

When I play a movie with external subtitles, VLC shows all subtitles in italic and/or bold, depending on font - I tested:

- **Arial, Times New Roman:** everything appears italic, regardless of whether it's marked with `<i>`. `<b>`-marked text appears bold+italic.
- **Tahoma, Calibri, Cambria:** everything appears bold, regardless of whether it's marked with `<b>`. `<i>`-marked text appears bold+italic.
- **Georgia:** everything appears bold+italic, regardless of `<b>` and `<i>`.
- **Garamond, Verdana:** all text appears correctly.

Notes:

- VLC 2.1.1 on Windows 8.1 (ever since VLC 2.0.5 on Windows 8)
- Subtitles default encoding is set to `Default (Windows-1252)`, happens regardless to encoding
- Happens with all .srt subtitles
- I've tried to disable formatted subtitles, in both "Kate overlay decoder" (WTH is that anyways) and "Text subtitles decoder". It disables formatting - but the default style still happens, according to the font (example: Arial - everything is italic).
- I don't have font problems outside of VLC subtitles.

Comment: Did you tried running `Reset VLC media player preferences` ?

Comment: Yes I did - no effect.

Comment: This is a known issue in Windows 8. No fix yet. See this VLC forum thread:
http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=104049

Comment: The title is misleading. Can someone rephrase it so it's not ambiguous?

Answer (score 2):

Change the subtitle language to "*Unknown*" or "*None*"

Comment: How would I do that? Options only have "preferred subtitle language", and that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I changed subtitles font to Calibri and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change tha font from Arial (or whatever is set) to Garamond or Verdana

Comment: "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."

Answer (score -2):

If you upgrade your Windows to Windows 10, like I did, the problem with the font goes away.
Try it!
http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/79/56/065a6eb1e0717956.jpg

Font is Arial.

Comment: Upgrading to a new version of the operating system seems like overkill for what is really a very minor font problem. Also, I've no idea what that link points to but I've no desire to follow it.